# Should I always set properties on props or state?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

While creating a custom `Component` in react-native, is it always preferable to have its attributes as part of either the state or the props, or are declarations "directly" inside the custom class sometimes good practice? (for instance, being `this` bound to an instance of the custom `Component`, having the `foo`attribute bound to `this.foo` instead of `this.state.foo` or `this.props.foo`)

Comment: when the `state` or `props` updates, this causes the component to re-render with the changes. However, "direct" attributes do not cause the component to re-render, so if you have a variable that you don't want it to cause any re-rending, I believe you can use "direct" attribute instead of `state`/`props`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> While creating a custom `Component` in react-native, is it always preferable to have its attributes as part of either the state or the props, or are declarations "directly" inside the custom class sometimes good practice?

It depends. If something isn't meant for state or as a prop then don't make it one. Not everything is part of state and not everything is a prop. There are consequences to putting something in state that's not supposed to be there, such as unnecessary and taxing re-renders and unexpected behavior.

Imagine we have an input element in a component. Let me break it down what conceptually belongs as a prop, state, and direct property of the component.

Think of props as arguments or input to a function, after all a React component is just a function. Props are used to create a component with different parameters, like attributes of an HTML element like the input's placeholder. If something is an attribute of the component such as the component's CSS, then it's conceptually *a prop*

State represents the *state of a component*, hence the name. Say we wanted to control our input, *we would have to manage the value of the text in the input*. If the component has different *states* based on interaction, then state is needed to keep track of what state the component is in and attributes of state such as the current value of the text in the input are needed. `this.state` holds whatever is necessary to manage the component's different states.

Say we want to focus on our input with `focus` (in the context of React, not React Native for illustrative purposes). We could use a ref to handle that and get the underlying DOM element. Since the underlying DOM element is not an argument or parameter of the component, it doesn't make sense as a prop. The underlying DOM element also is not needed to manage the input component's states. Thus it makes sense as a direct attribute of the component. Also, note that all your methods inside your component are directly set on the component, not inside state or props. A rule of thumb is if a value is not suited as a prop or in state *then don't put it there*.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! What do you mean exactly by "We could use a ref to handle that and get the underlying DOM element"?

Comment: I edited my first comment. Please answer my question, if possible

Comment: @bsam In the context of React Native, it wouldn't make sense because React Native doesn't have the DOM (sorry about that), but here's a link to the [React documentation about refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).